I can't login into Google Account on Android Studio Jellyfish/Koala
I have been trying to login into my Google account on Android Studio, but it didn't work. I am using AS Koala, but neither on AS Jellyfish. I just want to try the new Gemini integrated to the IDE. Does anybody know how to fix it?, Thanks!

I'm sorry, but "does not work" isn't an error description; it doesn't appear broken, there's nothing "to fix".
